# How do I replace an item in a list with a variable?

Tags: python-3.x, list, variables

How do I replace an item in a list with a variable?

```
def extension():
     global presents
     presents=[["Toy Car", 10.00, ""],["ES-335", 2500.00,""], ["Ben Teng Action Figure", 2.00, ""]]
     for row in presents:
       print(" ".join(map(str,row)))
     choice = str(input("Choose an item from the list "))
     count=0
     while count ==len(presents)+1:
         if choice==presents[count][0]:
```

I then want to insert the name that they previously gave in the program next to the item they chose within the open quote marks. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is to iterate over the list and insert the value into the 3rd position in the list.

See below:

```
array = [["foo1", "bar1", ""],["foo2", "bar2", ""],["foo3", "bar3", ""]]

for i in array:
    print(i)

for i in array:
    i[2] = "var"

for i in array:
    print(i)
```